# how to assign names to new table columns cells dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment ,this code can create new columns dynamically.I would like to be able to give a unique name to all cells belonging to the mother column.NB:the mother column is the tallest of them all with three columns always.Any thing with less columns is a child.
SO all the cells and the contents  in the first group must have a unique name identifer like say name="Bx_1name" to identify them from the next mother's contents(BX_2name);

```
    <table id="datble" class="form" border="1">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 1</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 2</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 3</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addColumn(element) {
var tr = $(element).closest("tr")[0];
var allTrs = $(tr).closest("table").find("tr");
var found = false;
allTrs.each(function(index, item) { 
    if (item == tr) {
        found = true;
        }
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        if (found) {

        td.innerHTML = '<label>Name</label>';
            td.innerHTML += '<input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />';
    }
    item.appendChild(td);
});
}
</script>
```

Javascript is wellcome too.the functionality must not be changed.it must be just like this;
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRcZN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it fits what you need.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qRcZN/1/)

```
var counter =0;
function addColumn(element) {
    var tr = $(element).closest("tr")[0];
    var allTrs = $(tr).closest("table").find("tr");
    var found = false;
    allTrs.each(function(index, item) { 
        if (item == tr) {
            found = true;
        }
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        if (found) {

            td.innerHTML = '<label>Name</label>';
            td.innerHTML += '<input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME['+counter+']" value="BX_NAME['+counter+']"/>';
            counter++;
        }
        item.appendChild(td);
    });
}
```

i used a global counter to increment each time a cell is made.

Comment: most people don't adise use of global variables.And you are simply counting through them,you are notdifferentiating between the mothers of the group.here you have an original column,if i click on add2,then that generated column is a child of the original that was on the page,and so does apply to add3.Thus making one group.But now if i click add1 again,then I have started another group2 for mother 2. Thanks for you effort

Answer (score 0):

this is just a hint you can implement this as you want to achieve. First assign same class name for all your input fields

```
 <table id="datble" class="form" border="1">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 1</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]"  class="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 2</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" class="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 3</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" class="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

then assign diffrent id's using jquery like following

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function (event) {
              var IDCount = 1;
            $('.text').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('id', IDCount);
                IDCount++;
});
</script>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: @NandalN No demo from you,but i can sense that your example will be no different from yaje's check out my comment to him plaese